# Pulling dates from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm having issues getting my date out of CD.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy"];
NSString *dateStr;
NSLog(@"%@",datesDictionary);
for (NSDictionary *diction in datesDictionary) {
    if ([diction objectForKey:@"date"] ) {
        ImportantDate *newDate = (ImportantDate *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ImportantDate" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        newDate.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"id"], nil) intValue]];
        dateStr = NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"date"], nil);
        NSLog(@"dateStr: %@",dateStr);
        newDate.date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
        NSLog(@"Date: %@",newDate.date);
        newDate.dayOfTheWeek = NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"dayOfTheWeek"], nil);
        newDate.eventType = NSLocalizedString([diction objectForKey:@"eventType"], nil);
    }
}
```

In my code when I'm logging `dateStr` it logs just fine. However when I log `newDate.date` I get a null value.

The rest of my values, being ints or strings come back just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the NSLog output for dateStr

Comment: You do not need to cast the result of `-insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:`. That call returns an `id`.

Comment: You also have a property on `ImportantDate` called `id`.  I would **strongly** recommend you rename that.  `id` is a reserved word.

Comment: The output of dateStr is: 2014-01-13

Comment: This is an issue with your configuration of NSDateFormatter and not core data. `dd-mm-yyyy` is not the correct format for `2014-01-13`. During debugging you should inspect all intermediate values. You'll notice that `[formatter dateFromString:dateStr];` will return nil.

Comment: @bnjmn.myes, Martin asked for the data needed to solve your issue.  Your code also needs other help otherwise you are going to have more problems down the road.

Comment: Good luck with that attitude.  You will go far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the date formatter. It has to correspond to the string passed in your dictionary.

It appears that in your dictionary contains dates in the following format.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

But your date formatter (that is used to read in these strings) is

```
"dd-mm-yyyy"
```

This cannot work, so your returned date is `nil`. Please not the difference between `M` and `m` for months and minutes respectively.